# What happens when we publish a web part page which is in edit mode?

Tags: web-part

1. Edit Page.
2. Modify Shared web part.
3. Change some properties.
4. Click OK.
5. Publish.

What is happening between steps 4 and 5 ?
(wrt content and configuration databases)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact details but I do know that the web part property values were not versioned with the page in SharePoint 2007 but they are in SharePoint 2010. So, in SharePoint 2010, if you were to restore the previous version of the page the web part property values would be rolled back as well.

See: [2010: Versioning of Web Part instances](http://www.bluedoglimited.com/SharePointThoughts/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=305)

Comment: thanks Rob :)

Good Information!!
But still waiting for my answer.